# Why is 'Infinity' not allowed in Erlang's floats?

Tags: floating-point, erlang, elixir, precision

Erlang (and by extension Elixir) supports floating-point numbers.

Some possible Floats:

- `1.2345`
- `1.0e10`
- `1.0e-42`

Erlang supports NaN (`nan.` in Erlang) (I am however yet to discover a method that outputs `nan` itself).

However, Erlang does not have support for `Infinity`. While common standards like IEEE-754 state that one should return `Infinity` when doing things like `1.0/0.0`, instead, Erlang throws a `bad arithmetic error`.

The same happens when attempting to make floats that are 'too large' like `1.0e400`.

There's probably some (historical?) reason behind this.

Comment: Erlang supports neither NaN nor infinity - it looks like you've got the atom `nan` instead, which is not a float. I don't know why Erlang doesn't support those values, though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Erlang does all sorts of "bad" things with floats (not quite IEEE 754 binary64): conflates -0 and +0 to 0, doesn't do +-SNaNs, +-QNaNs, +-denormals or +-infinity.

For actual, scientific computations with precise error handling, it's probably worth dropping into another language either with a `Port`, doing some RPC or writing C/C++ NIF.

Reference: http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html

**Update:** I wrote a trivial ieee754 module [here](https://gist.github.com/steakknife/3aac023d1b8bccb1096159e5752d1172) which classifies binary64 floats and converts those that Erlang supports.

Answer (score 6):

Looking in  ./erts/emulator/sys/unix/sys_float.c

it appears to me that Erlang is using the underlying strtod implementation to convert to "standard" C floats.

On most unix systems, floating point was not implemented to that standard
at the time Erlang was created, but values that would generate Infinity instead generate fpe signal errors.