# Why is this erlang binary failing binary_to_term/1?

Tags: erlang

I am passing this binary to binary_to_term/1.  As far as I can tell, it is well-formed and should be passing, but it is causing a badarg error.  Can anyone tell me why?

```
> B = <<131,104,3,100,0,2,111,107,100,0,7,82,69,65,76,83,88,80,
      108,0,0,0,1,70,127,240,0,0,0,0,7,162,106>>.

> binary_to_term(B).
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  binary_to_term/1
        called as binary_to_term(<<131,104,3,100,0,2,111,107,100,0,7,82,69,65,76,83,88,
                                   80,108,0,0,0,1,70,127,240,0,0,...>>)
```

Going by the documentation, the binary should break down like this:

```
131  %% encoding version number
104 3  %% a tuple with three elements
100 0 2 111 107  %% the atom length 2 'ok'
100 0 7 82 69 65 76 83 88 80  %% the atom length 7 'REALSXP'
108 0 0 0 1  %% a list with one element
70 127 240 0 0 0 0 7 162  %% a float encoded in eight bytes
106  %% end of list
```

Giving something like:

```
{ok, 'REALSXP', [123.456]}
```

The only bit that doesn't seem completely clear is the float.  Is the eight byte sequence

```
<<127,240,0,0,0,0,7,162>>
```

valid for a float encoded as "8 bytes in big-endian IEEE format"?

If not the float section, what else about this binary is tripping up binary_to_term?

With thanks and best wishes

Ivan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `<<127,240,0,0,0,0,7,162>>` is a NaN value in 64 bit IEEE float and Erlang doesn't support creating NaN and Infinity float values at all (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080582/why-is-infinity-not-allowed-in-erlangs-floats)).

```
1> <<Sign:1, Exponent:11, Fraction:52>> = <<127,240,0,0,0,0,7,162>>.
<<127,240,0,0,0,0,7,162>>
2> Exponent.
2047
3> Fraction.
1954
4> 16#7ff.
2047
```

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#Exponent_encoding:

> The exponents 000<sub>16</sub> and 7ff<sub>16</sub> have a special meaning:
>
> ```
> 00016 is used to represent a signed zero (if M=0) and subnormals (if M≠0); and 
>
> 7ff16 is used to represent ∞ (if M=0) and NaNs (if M≠0),
> ```
>
> where M is the fraction mantissa.

If you change those 8 bytes to a valid, non NaN/Infinity 64 bit IEEE float, everything works as expected:

```
1> binary_to_term(<<131,104,3,100,0,2,111,107,100,0,7,82,69,65,76,83,88,80,108,0,0,0,1,70,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,106>>).
{ok,'REALSXP',[0.0]}
```

Comment: Brilliant answer! Thanks very much!  The binary is coming in from a C port and a NaN fits perfectly.  I'll catch it on the C side and change what's sent through.