# Binary Tree Maximum Path in Erlang

Tags: erlang

The [Binary Tree Maximum Path](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-maximum-path-sum/) problem can be solved in using DFS.
Here is a possible [solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-maximum-path-sum/discuss/329033/Python-bottom-up-DFS-solution) using this approach in Python.

```
def maxPathSum(self, root):
    def maxSum(root):
        if not root:
            return 0
        l_sum = maxSum(root.left)
        r_sum = maxSum(root.right)
        l = max(0, l_sum)
        r = max(0, r_sum)
        res[0] = max(res[0], root.val + l + r)
        return root.val + max(l, r)
    
    res = [-float('inf')]
    maxSum(root)
    return res[0]
```

I am trying to use the same approach in Erlang. Assuming a *node* would look like:

```
{Value, Left, Right}
```

I came up with:

```
max_sum(undefined) -> 0;
max_sum({Value, Left, Right}) ->
    LeftSum = max(0, max_sum(Left)),
    RightSum = max(0, max_sum(Right)),
    %% Where to store the max? Should I use the process dictionary?
    %% Should I send a message?
    Value + max(LeftSum, RightSum).

max_path_sum(Root) ->
  %% Bonus question: how to represent -infinity in Erlang?
  max_sum(Root)
```

There are no global variables in Erlang. How can I keep track of the maximum during DFS? The only things that come to my mind are to use the process dictionary or an ETS table or maybe have a different process that can keep the maximum, but maybe I am overthinking and there is a more simple and idiomatic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most "erlangish" way would be to pass the global maximum as a second parameter, and return it along with the local maximum:

```
max_sum(undefined, GlobalMax) -> {0, GlobalMax};
max_sum({Value, Left, Right}, GlobalMax0) ->
    {LeftSum, GlobalMax1} = max(0, max_sum(Left, GlobalMax0)),
    {RightSum, GlobalMax2} = max(0, max_sum(Right, GlobalMax1)),
    NewGlobalMax =
        case GlobalMax2 of
            undefined ->
                Value + LeftSum + RightSum
            _ ->
                max(GlobalMax2, Value + LeftSum + RightSum)
        end,
    {Value + max(LeftSum, RightSum), NewGlobalMax}.

max_path_sum(Root) ->
    {_, GlobalMax} = max_sum(Root, undefined),
    GlobalMax.
```

Erlang [doesn't support infinity values in floats](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38080582/113848), so I used the atom `undefined` to represent a smallest value instead.